# Suppress submodules from appearing in namespace w/ __init__.py

Tags: python, package

How does one avoid multiple locations of a class/method/etc. within a python package's namespace? Consider a package with the following directory structure and code:

```
dummyproj/
├── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

.

```
# main.py
# =======
def dummy_func():
    print "hello world"
```

.

```
# __init__.py
# ===========
from main import *
```

With this construction, the function `dummy_func` is available from within the package. However, it is also available from a submodule called `main`. For example:

```
>>> import dummyproj
>>> dir(dummyproj)
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'dummy_func',
 'main']
>>> dummyproj.dummy_func()
hello world
>>> dummyproj.main.dummy_func()
hello world
```

How would I prevent `main` from showing up in the `dummy_proj` namespace? My understanding is that it would be bad form to include the code for `dummy_func` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: So it is an acceptable practice the way I have it written above even though `dummy_func` appears in two places?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Lukas. I have a little familiarity with the `requests` module, so it is an effective example to make your point. Would you mind submitting something to this effect as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (in a clean and commonly accepted way).

But the question is, why would you want to? Ideally the users of your library would use your documentation in order to learn about your library's API, and wouldn't have to resort to using `dir()`.

And if I'm debugging your library, which I'm probably doing if using `dir()`, I wouldn't want to have the library's structure obfuscated from me.

So just structuring your package the way you did in your example is perfectly acceptable, most libraries are built that way:

- Use submodules / packages, possibly several levels of them, to structure the code in a sensible way
- Then provide convenience imports at the top-level package for often used functions / classes / etc.

---

A very good example is the `requests` module:

```
import requests
requests.get(url)
```

The `get()` function is provided as a [convenience import at the top-level package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py#L60), and is also documented that way ([quickstart docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) | [API docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.get)). But the `get()` function actually lives in [`requests.api.get`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L51).

---

Another good example is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), which even uses several level of convenience imports:

The `Column` class lives in [`sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L835). But it is provided as a convenience import as [`sqlalchemy.schema.Column`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/schema.py#L19), and even at the very top as [`sqlalchemy.Column`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L100). *(Though the `sqlalchemy.schema` namespace is simply for compatibility reasons as far as I can tell).*

Answer (score 1):

Just delete it in your`__init__.py`file:

```
# __init__.py
# ===========
from main import *
del main
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing this. (atleast that I am aware of)

You could either just use `del` to clean it up, or you could use a function to generate the module for you. Something like this: (in `__init__.py`).

```
def __init__mod():
    from main import dummy_func

    g = globals()
    g['dummy_func'] = dummy_func

__init__mod()
```